# Verb for how much space a file takes up?

Tags: word-request, verbs, verb-usage

When I was a kid my dad used to say (in Norwegian):

> This file **weighs** four megabytes.

Or maybe one could say

> This file **consumes** four megabytes.

Or simply

> This file **is** four megabytes.

But somehow I'm not sure.

What are some good *verbs* I can use for this?

Comment: We don't have a verb in English which is customarily used in this context. A native speaker would almost always say _The file size is 4Mb,_ or even shorten it to _The file is 4Mb_ (as you have it.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Sure we do. Us native speakers say "the file _takes up_ 4MB".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There are many verbs in use, but as the plethora of answers and comments illustrates, no specific verb is _customarily_ used.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: As a native speaker, I cannot find a phrase strong enough to indicate how much I disagree with that statement. I do not consider two short posts on a website to be valid evidence to the contrary. "Takes up" certainly _is_ the customary expression. Of course I cannot promise that literally every single English speaker is aware of it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - _Take(s) up_ is a fine choice, as is _is,_ and as is the use of _size,_ as is _comprises._ The question asks for "some good verbs," and he now has several choices. I'm confident that he can choose the one he likes best.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll buy "*Takes up* certainly is *a* customary expression" but I think "*the* (unique? most often used?) customary expression" needs some evidence to support it.

Comment: @Fiksdal You know what? It just occurred to me that **weighs** is a marvelous way to put it. Maybe you can introduce the usage, and by the year 2025 it will have become common parlance! Credit to your Father!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This native speaker thinks "takes up" sounds weird.  "The file takes 4 MB" sounds better, though I would still just use "is".

Comment: At risk of being pedantic, the amount of space used on disk is not usually the same as the actual file size, depending on the filesystem in use. For example with a 4kb sector size a 5000 byte file will take up 8192 bytes on disk. You should consider "the file is 5000 bytes" and "the file takes up 5000 bytes" mean very different things

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm a native speaker, and a programmer to boot, and I've never said "takes up" for that (I'm in the "is" crowd), so please kindly unsubscribe me from your "us" mailing list, thanks!

Comment: @JasonC - I, too, have a programming background. I might not use "takes up" in the context of, "That file takes up 5MB," but I can imagine myself using that phrasal verb in part of a longer sentence – e.g., _That 5GB file takes up more than half the space on the thumbdrive._

Comment: @J.R. Sure; although in that case, "5GB" is no longer the object of "takes up", so "takes up" isn't really related to the verb being asked about in this question any more, at least if we go by the OP's examples. There, you've changed "The file ___ 5GB" to "The 5GB file", the rest of that phrase is incidental.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you simply want to say how big a file is, then **is** is fine.

> This video **is** 770 megabytes

If you want to emphasize how much space it is taking up, you can use [occupy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/occupy) in the sense **fill, exist in, or use a place**

> This video will **occupy** most of the free space on my phone.

Comment: I think there's some connotation difference between the two.  I think we typically use "is" in cases where you're not really worried about how big the file is, but you're simply providing information.  In cases where you're worried about how big it is, such as whether it will fit on a CD or not, we may switch over to "occupy" or "consumes" to make it clear that we are working with a finite resource.

Comment: @CortAmmon: exactly, it's a question of perspective:  **occupy**, **consume** and **take up** specify the effect on the outside, whereas **contain**, **consist of** and **comprise** specifies what is inside. **is** is completely neutral- it emphasizes neither external effect nor internal content.

Comment: @CortAmmon I still use *is* for that. "This disc image is 7.34 GB, will it fit on a DVD?" I mean, we often use the size as an adjective in its own right, and *is* fits the pattern: "The 12 megabyte text file" ⇒ "The text file is 12 megabytes".

Comment: +1 for occupy: "This file occupies two hundred megabytes of disk space." *Is* is generally fine, but a file isn't anything until it is stored on disk, at which point it is occupying disk space, regardless of whether that disk is a hard disk, a DVD, a flash disk or anything else.

Comment: Just a note that if you say *is*, there is an implied *big* or *large* after the measurement: "This video is 770 megabytes large." This is similar to how you can say that a ruler is 30 centimetres, but it would be more accurate to say that it's 30 centimetres long.

Comment: @Schism Well, I dunno. It would be awkward if somebody added "big", "large", "long", whatever to that in a sentence, which contrasts with how natural it is when adding "long" after a distance measurement. Also I contend that the presence of "long" on the end doesn't affect the accuracy of the statement: "The ruler is 30 centimeters" carries no less informational content than "The ruler is 30 centimeters long". "Long" only serves to differentiate from "wide" or "thick" or "high" or "tall", etc. but we don't need that because of context. It's possible that "accurate" wasn't the best word choice.

Comment: @JavaLatte Further to your point, these different verbs have different means/values. A 770MB Video FILE might OCCUPY more or less than 770MB of SPACE. Yet the *file* IS still 770MB in SIZE. For an analogy, a FAMILY may have 10 members, or be 10 people in SIZE. But they might occupy a 20 bedroom mansion, due to inefficient housing. They could also be squashed into a a squalid 2 bedroom flat.

Comment: @Aron, That certainly is an interesting point for a non-rewriteable medium like CD-ROM. A file might be just 25 Mb, but once the CD-ROM is written, you could argue that file occupies the whole CD-ROM, I would, however, stll prefer to say that the file occupies only 25Mb out of the 700 megabytes on the CD-ROM, and the rest is wasted. In the opposite direction, you can zip a file: the original file is 25 Mb, but the zip-file is/occupies only 11Mb.

Answer (score 18):

What is wrong with **take up**?

> The file takes up  four megabytes.

[Example](http://introcomputing.org/bits-bytes-2.html):

> One kilobyte (KB) is a collection of about 1000 bytes. A page of ordinary roman alphabetic text **takes** about 2 kilobytes to store (about one byte per letter). A typical short email would also **take up** just 1 or 2 kilobytes. Text is one of the most naturally compact types of data at about one byte required to store each letter. In non-roman alphabets, such as Kanji, the storage **takes up** 2 or 4 bytes per "letter" which is still pretty compact compared to audio and images

Definition ('take up')

> to fill or use an amount of space or time
>
> *The table takes up too much room.*
>   *I won't take up any more of your time.*
>   *Her time is fully taken up with writing.*

([Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/take-up_2))

Answer (score 6):

I think most English speakers say "is" or "takes". "This file is 4 MB" or "This file takes 4 MB."

We sometimes say "requires", especially if we're discussing whether the person has sufficient room on their device to hold it. For example when you install new software, you often get a message that says something like, "requires 100 MB, 280 MB available", and then if the "requires" is more than the "available" you get an error message. Or more casually, you might say to a co-worker, "This file requires 3 GB. Do you have enough room for it on your thumb drive?"

I've never heard an English-speaker say "weighs 4 MB", though it would make a wonderfully descriptive word for the idea.

If you said "consumes" people would know what you meant and would probably not think it incredibly odd wording, but few would actually say that.

Answer (score 3):

12 megabytes are the size of the file. In English, sizes are *measured*. Some measurements, like weight, happen to have a special verb attached to them, derived from the measurement process. "This potato weighs 200 grams" means that, when you *weigh* the potato, the output of the measuring process is *200 grams*.

We have never created a special word for the measuring process of information. Maybe information theorists have one, but it has never made it into common culture. So, if you insist on using a verb, you cannot go more specific than

> This file measures 12 megabytes.

As others have noted, this is not typical usage. Nobody thinks of measuring a file as a process, because the information about the measurement is available without any action on our part. So we simply use the contraction

> This file['s size] is 12 megabytes.

And that's all there is to it.

Sometimes the word you are looking for doesn't exist, because nobody needs it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally people use the word *size* for this. For example "What size is the file?" or "The file size is 6 megabytes".

Comment: You did not answer the question.

Comment: It is true that the question asked for a verb and my answer is not a verb, however my answer is the most useful because this is how a native English speaker would express this, and I think this is what the questioner really wanted to know.

Comment: @bikeman868 The question is tagged [tag:verb] and [tag:verb-usage], it also emphasises _verb_ in the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many verbs that can be used to convey the sense the OP wants to.

There's nothing wrong with the verb take (up), but the verb occupy is more common and idiomatic. We can also use the verbs consist of or comprise, but the usage of the comorise is more formal. The verb be can also be used as a main verb. So the following sentences are possibe:

This file takes (up) 35 megabytes.

This is a 35-megabyte file.

This file is 35 megabytes.

This file consists of 35 megabytes.

This file comprises 35 megabytes.

However,  the sentence "This file occupies 35 megabytes seems more appropriate than the sentence "This file takes (up) 35 megabytes".

You can also say:

This file has a storage capacity of 35 megabytes.

Comment: I'm not sure of "This file has a storage capacity of 35 megabytes."  I think that's actually the opposite meaning.  "This storage device has a capacity of 35 megabytes / Great! that means it can store my file."

Comment: Both 'comprises' and 'consists of' sound definitely wrong. Both of these mean 'is constructed from' - the megabytes aren't components of the file, but a measurement of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the sort of usage for which the English verb **comprise** is appropriate:

> The file **comprises** 4Mb.

I propose, however, that we standarize instead on the elegant Norwegian expression:

> The file **weighs** 4Mb.

Comment: You're not holding your breath for what?

Comment: @Fiksdal I'm not holding my breath waiting for even _English_ speakers to adopt the verb _comprise_ in this usage - or even to use it correctly! (The usage of _comprise_ and _compose_ is a longstanding point of contention amongst language enthusiasts.)

Comment: Ah, alright, I see.

Comment: OP asked for a good verb, not one that you admit yourself nobody else actually uses.

Comment: I gather then that you think **comprise** is not a good verb. Your comprehension is lacking here: I did not say that "nobody else" uses it. Hardly anyone uses the verb **deign** either, yet it is certainly "good," and if more people did, it might be "better!" So with **comprise.** The objective is to _increase_ vocabulary, not to reduce it to the bare necessities.

Comment: Can you actually comprise quantities, or only discrete things? "The house comprises four rooms" is obviously okay, but "the pool comprises ten thousand gallons" and "the file comprises 4 megabytes" seem distinctly wrong to me.

Comment: A _megabyte,_ like a _room,_ is a discrete entity, and we number things liike that, I think. The dictionary tells us only: _to include or consist of._ I'm willing to take it as an authority. Some may demur.

Comment: @P.E.Dant is a megabyte still a discrete entity if I say "the file comprises 4.63 megabytes"?

Comment: @P.E.Dant To me, it's like saying "The jar comprises 2kg of sand" (megabytes) - we can also say "The jar comprises 2158306 grains of sand" (bytes). While we can count it, it seems "fluid".

Comment: @P.E.Dant, maybe you should include a link to the definition that supports this usage. The definition I found certainly doesn't:  **to have as parts or members, or to be those parts or members** - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/comprise

Comment: @P.E.Dant Lightness Races in Orbit meant that the verb may not be well-understood, and it's better to choose another verb, or explain what it means.

Comment: @ErikKonstantopoulos The question was posed by Fiksdal, not by lightnessracesinorbit, and he asked for _good verbs._ He is more than capable of choosing which one he thinks is good. If someone doesn't understand a given word, I advise them not to use it.

Comment: @JavaLatte Dictionary.com has _to include or contain; to consist of._ You would not, then, say that a file consists of N megabytes, I suppose. To me, a bit is a thing, even if a file contains several million of them. I would not usually say that my cup comprises 9.3 ounces of coffee, but it wouldn't distress me to hear it said. Also see this [search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&hl=en-us&ei=oZqwV_nhGcL4mAHvuJawAQ&q=%22comprises+8+ounces%22&oq=%22comprises+8+ounces%22).

Comment: @PEDant, it's a question of perspective:  When we look at a file in a folder, we note only the effect on the outside world- the amount of space it **takes up** or **occupies**. When we open a file and look inside, we don't see bits: we see content. The file **contains** a document. The document **consists of** or **comprises** several chapters and some appendices. The appendices **include**  references.

Comment: @JavaLatte There is a fascinating question here for linguists, I think, because we speak here of a model which is novel: our language has not evolved as rapidly as the world in which it is spoken! In one sense, the file itself contains _only_ bits, which encode (and there may be a better word for that) the content. The bits themselves are "content neutral." When software "looks at" a file, it "sees" only bits. When a human looks at a file, she sees the content represented by bits. Of what, then, is a file composed? What does a file comprise?

Comment: @JavaLatte I think we have a bit of _thread drift_ here. The question "How big is that file?" can be appropriately answered either with _Oh, 100 megs._ or with _200 pages, I guess,_ depending upon the era. That is the form of the question here, not "What's in the file?"